# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AccountsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure what to do to fix this error. As soon as I press the 'create account' I get an error saying Could not find table 'accounts'.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

   def new 
      @account = Account.new   
   end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Signed up successfully'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end 
private
  def account_params
     params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain)
  end
end
```

error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'accounts'): 
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:4:in `new
```

Could not find table 'accounts'

```
Started GET "/accounts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-06 13:19:40 -0500
Processing by AccountsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'accounts'):
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:4:in `new'


Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch 
/templates/rescues/_source.erb (10.1ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.3ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (51.2ms)


Started GET "/accounts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-06 13:19:41 -0500
Processing by AccountsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'accounts'):
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:4:in `new'


Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.7ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered /home/shuabe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (38.4ms)
```

I'm not sure, but does it have anything to do with migration? I haven't generated any migration. If it is migration, how do I generate a table for the accounts controller?

I'm not currently using devise and the only gems I'm using are:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc



group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
```

Comment: Check your database, do you actually have a table called `accounts`? In rails, if you created your model using one of the generators (such as `rails g model Account`), then a migration would have been made for you. If you manually created the model, you've made some extra work for yourself, and will need to [create the migration yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14452094/877472).

Comment: Did you create an Account model? did you migrate the database rake db:migrate?

Comment: @RailsOuter They'd actually get a different error if they forgot to migrate (usually something saying "Pending Migrations").

Comment: you're right Paul, my bad.

Comment: @PaulRichter I created the accounts model manually. Is it rails g migration Account? And if I do, do I fill it with "add_column :account" or "add_column :new, :create"?

Comment: @JamesRocky See my answer below, should answer that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, the problem is you've created the `Account` class/model manually. This is generally a very bad idea; not fatal, but problematic, as you've experienced.

Normally, in Rails you would generate your models using one of the generators, such as `rails g model Account [account fields]`, or `rails g scaffold Account [account fields]`. When doing so, you receive the model itself and the corresponding migration (as well as all the testing files you need). Since you've indicated you created the model file manually, you have none of that, and need to either:

- Create it manually:

  run the following:

  `rails g migration create_accounts [account fields]`

  where `[your account fields]` would be whatever fields are necessary. For example,

  `... account_name:string account_status:string ...`
- OR, remove your Account class for now, and regenerate it using one of the generators above

If you're new to Rails, check out the [Getting Started guided](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running), which illustrates what I'm referring to here.